# Restore a deleted Commit

Tags: git, bitbucket

I was working on a project today, and i committed a month worth of changes,
then I did a major change in the project which broke the whole project.

So I reset to the previous commit using

```
git reset --hard <commit>
```

and then

```
git push origin HEAD --force
```

after than all my previous changes were gone because I choose the wrong commit to reset to (not sure).
and whenever i write any git command now i get (not a git repository).

and I opened Bit Bucket and both commits are gone.
Is there ANYWAY to restore that commit PLEASE?

The project is a groovy on Grails project.
I'm using intelliJ

Answer (score 1):

Your *local* repository keeps copies of commits for at least 30 days by default.  The repository over on Bitbucket probably does not.

If you have not erased your *local* repository, look there for the commits.  Use `git reflog` or `git reflog <branchname>`.  The reflog for `HEAD` holds the hash IDs that `HEAD` represented in the past.  The reflog for the given branch name, such as `master`, holds the hash IDs that that branch name represented in the past.

If you were on branch `xyzzy` when you did the `git reset --hard <commit>`, `xyzzy@{1}` represents the hash ID that `xyzzy` held *before* this `git reset --hard`, so `git reflog xyzzy` will show you the commit you want.  You can now `git reset --hard <commit>` to *that* hash ID, pushing all the numbers up by one, i.e., what was `xyzzy@{1}` is now `xyzzy@{2}` and the wrong commit hash ID you picked last time is now `xyzzy@{1}`.  Meanwhile `xyzzy` (aka `xyzzy@{0}`) is now the hash ID you just picked *this* time.

You can now `git push origin HEAD` or `git push origin xyzzy` to send this hash ID (and the commit(s), if they've lost it/them) to the Git at Bitbucket, and ask them to set their `xyzzy` to this hash ID.  You will only need `--force` if this operation loses some commit(s) on their end.

Comment: I've tried but it says not a git repository, then I tried cloning the project to another folder and using git reflog and it only showed the first commit

Comment: "not a git repository" means just what it says. Did you remove your Git repository? If you kept it, be sure you're *in* it when you run Git commands. If you removed it, it's gone: Git can't stop you from doing that.

Comment: No I didn't deleted I think something corrupted the files. So there is nothing I can do now?

Comment: This kind of corruption shouldn't happen, but if you've had a power failure (or battery failure on laptop) while working, or a system crash, sometimes what happens is that the `.git/HEAD` file gets removed entirely. In this case you can sometimes get your repository to work again by creating a `.git/HEAD` file containing the single line `ref: refs/heads/master` (to put yourself on your `master` branch). If that's not it—if you still have a valid `HEAD` file in `.git`—try searching for other methods of recovering from a damaged Git repository.